# Flutter how to wrap widgets around a fixed/positioned widget

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to wrap Widgets around a fixed Widget (e.g. Positioned at the top right, preferably without having to know the size in advance), as shown in the screenshot below? I am aware of the [float_column](https://pub.dev/packages/float_column) package, however this seems to only work for wrapping text, rather than for generic widgets.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Wrap() layout widget? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Comment: Yes, this works fine for wrapping widgets in a rectangular area. My question is how to wrap arbitrary widgets around fixed-position widgets placed in that rectangular area.

Comment: use `Flow` widget then - you need to write your custom layout delegate class which should not be longer than 20 lines of code